# Use a separate NIC for ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, routing, network-adapter

I have two NICs. I want to use one (eth0) for connecting to Host_A using SSH and the other (eth1) for everything else.

I also run a Socks proxy through that SSH connection to Host_A. All traffic through that proxy should also use eth0 (the same as the ssh connection itself).

How do I set this up?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that the two NICs are connected to different networks.

**EDIT 2:** After adding the route to Host_A, the new default route and deleting the old default route I can successfully connect using ssh to Host_A. (Thanks @MariusMatutiae)

It does however take "forever" for the password prompt to appear. With only eth0 active it appears much faster.

I can also not use the SOCKS5 proxy I create by specifying -D 8080 when connecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call IP1 the IP address of the router on eth1, and IP0 the IP address of the router on eth0. Then these two commands

```
 sudo route add default  gw IP1
 sudo route add -host IP_of_Host_A gw IP0
```

assures that all of your applications will go the `best way`, i.e., the one with the smallest metric, and you can force ssh to use eth0 by means of, (assuming that eth0 has IP address xxx.yyy.www.zzz):

```
  ssh -b xxx.yyy.www.zzz me@IP_Host_A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I've updated my question with some information I really should have remembered to include from the start!

Comment: @Tobbe Edited my answer to reflect your changes

Comment: Had to delete my old default route (it was using eth0). Other than that this works!

Comment: One more thing however; Would it be possible to make it possible to use the host name when connecting through ssh instead of the IP address? And use, for example, 10.10.2.0/24 instead of 10.10.2.115 when specifying the route? I want this to be able to handle a Host_A that doesn't have a static IP address.

Comment: Still one thing that doesn't work, and that's the SOCKS5 proxy `ssh -D 8080 -b xxx.yyy.www.zzz me@IP_Host_A`

Comment: @Tobbe About message 1: yes, edit (as sudo) the file /etc/hosts, insert a line as follows xxx.yyy.www.zzzTABhostname. About message: let me think a little.

Comment: That's not the IP address I meant. Sorry. I mean I want to be able to do `ssh -D 8080 -b xxx.yyy.www.zzz me@Host_A` instead of `ssh -D 8080 -b xxx.yyy.www.zzz me@IP_Host_A`

Comment: My bad. I meant the right thing, but gave you the wrong option. In /etc/hosts, put a line that says IP_Host_ATABname_of_Host_A. Notice the Tab in between.

Comment: That doesn't help me though. I still can't connect to Host_A if it's given a new IP (by the DHCP server for example)

Comment: Just had to add routes for the DNS servers on Host_A's network as well and everything started to work! Thanks a lot for your help!